# how to config the `router` in the `dev` environment?

Tags: angularjs, router

Using my local host, i was worked my `angular` app. i moved this app to my `dev` environment, where i am working now.

But after i move to `dev` my `router` not working. i guess i need to do some configuration to work that. But i tried up to changing my `routes` but nothing works.

my new dev app url : `http://azvsp14devapp01:123/_layouts/15/cpmd/public/` - in the public folder my `index.html` nested.

here is my app.js :

```
(function () {

    "user strict";

    angular.module("tcpApp", ["ngRoute","ngResource", "ngAnimate"])

    .run(['$route', function ($route) {

        $route.reload();

    }])

    .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {


        // $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

        $routeProvider
            .when ("123/_layouts/15/cpmd/public/", { //trying for equalient of `/`
                templateUrl : "views/login/login.html",
                controller  : "loginController",
                className   : "body-login"
        });

        $routeProvider
            .when ("/lock", {
                templateUrl : "views/lock/lockScreen.html",
                controller  : "lockScreenController",
                className   : "body-lockScreen"
        });

        $routeProvider
            .when ("/home", {
                templateUrl : "views/home/home.html",
                controller  : "homeController",
                className   : "body-home"
        });

        $routeProvider
            .when ("/projectSummary/:id", {
                templateUrl : "views/projectSummary/projectSummary.html",
                controller  : "projectSummaryController",
                className   : "body-projectSummary"
        });

        $routeProvider
            .when ("/projectDetails", {
                templateUrl : "views/projectDetails/projectDetails.html",
                controller  : "projectDetailsController",
                className   : "body-projectDetails"
        });

        $routeProvider
            .otherwise ({
                redirectTo:'123/_layouts/15/cpmd/public/'
        });
    })

})();
```

Comment: Have you checked if app uses same ports? azvsp14devapp01:123 is 123, and before it was too?

Comment: no, before i didn't use the port the one at present i use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
"123/_layouts/15/cpmd/public/"
```

to

```
"/"
```

In both **when** and **otherwise**.

This because router place with index.html treats as root.